# How to update React State in an array of objects? Update if id exists, otherwise append

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

the parent component gets the object from the child component through callback function. I want to check if the object with the specfic rowID exists, if it exists then it should update the object with the  passed value "val", otherwise it should append the object inside the state array.
My answer is appending correctly but I am unable the update the values, please help me out. the object which is being passed is attached at the end.

```
const [state, setState] = React.useState([]);

const existingProduct = state && state.find((product) => product.rowID == index);
if (!!existingProduct === false) {
  return setState((prevState) => [...prevState, object]);
}
console.log(state);

let payload = {
          quantity: quantityRef.current && 
          quantityRef.current.value,
          name: product && product.NAME,
          unit: product && product.UNIT,
          PRICE: product && product.PRICE,
          oldQuantity: oldQuantity,
          rowID: id,
        };
```

Comment: Can you show what you've tried and didn't work? If I understand correctly you're trying to update an existing object in the array. Also, your code snippet is incomplete and a bit confusing, could you post more?

Comment: i think i have solved, could you have a look  at it.

Comment: That's one way to do it, I guess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before answering I have to mention `!!existingProduct === false` is very confusing to read. You can simply do `!existingProduct` to achieve the same result.

Your code is missing some parts so I'm gonna have to infer, but I assume the `index` value does what you want, and you're already detecting if the product is present or not in the array. And you're appending the new product in the `if`, so what we need is an `else`.

What I would do is copying the state into a new array, replacing the value in the new array, and setting this new array as the new state. To know which position of the array you need to update you can use the [`findIndex()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) method instead of `find()`. So instead of `existingProduct` being an object, it's the index of the array that contains that object (so I would call it `existingProductIdx` just to make it clear):

```js
if (existingProductIdx === -1) { // product doesn't exist in the array
  ...
} else { // product exists
  const newSate = [...state] // creates a copy of the current array
  newState[existingProductIdx] = payload // set the position of the array to payload (or whatever should be the new value)
  return setState(newState)
}
```

A few notes:

- I assume you're doing this inside a function that you want to return earlier and that's why you have that `return` statement. Otherwise you don't need it
- I don't remember right now but I'm pretty sure `setState` has no return value, so instead you can do `setState(newState); return;`. Or, you may not need to return at all.
- I would suggest you change the `state` and `setState` variable names to something more meaningful, like `products` and `setProducts`
- Again, I hope that middle section of your code sample belongs into a function, otherwise that would mess up your component (which should return a render function)